# Sending a command to running Python script

Tags: python, bash, xdotool

I have a Python script that runs openCV to play a video. If the user presses the "c" button on the keyboard, OpenCV will save the frame that shows at the time the user clicks the "c" button.

Problem is, I want to save this automatically through a bash script - meaning, at some point, I want my bash script to "simulate" the "c" button being pressed so that it can take that snap.

My (surely  very un-pythonic) approach was making a small bashscript that utilizes `xdotool`. This is what it looks like:

```
pid=$(pgrep -f "python cv_player.py")
echo $pid
while IFS= read line; do
  if [[ "${line}" =~ (0x)([0-9a-z]+)([ ][- ][0-9]+[ ])([0-9]*) ]]; then
    winId="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    pid="${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
    if [[ "${pid}" -eq "${pid}" ]]; then
      WIND_IDS+=("${winId}")
    fi
  fi
done < <(wmctrl -lp)

if [ "${#WIND_IDS[@]}" -gt 0 ]; then
  xdotool key --window "${WIND_IDS[@]}" c 
fi
```

It finds the `pid` of the python file, finds the window ID, and simulates the "c" button being pressed.

This doesnt work. Could be because my bash is wrong...

Anyways, what *is* the pythonic way of doing this? (without dealing with sockets...plz...). Or, if you can tell me what's wrong  with my bash script, that'd be cool too. But I really just wanna know the correct way to do this pythonically. I don't even need it to be a button pressed, could just be anything I send it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show a sample output of `wmctrl -lp` to check your script? Without it it is not easy to reproduce your issue

Comment: But on the first look, aren't you use `pid` variable wrongly here? once initially in the script to store a value and then later in a loop. It looks wrong.